# How to change the font of all objects in a project?

Tags: c#, object, fonts, properties

I'm working on Visual Studio 2015,C# with windows forms; I was wondering if there is an easy way to change this property for all objects in my project, without having to change them manually.

I have seen some methods that change the font for all objects in a form, but this will have to be implemented in every form; and if I want to change it after 50 forms it will be bothersome

Any  ideas?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What type of project is this?

Comment: It's a financial program, it's meant to be a really big one, which is why I wanna wrap all these design options from the beginning

Comment: I think he meant what type of VS project - C#/VB, WinForms, ASP.NET, etc.

Comment: C# with vs2015, Sorry!

Comment: Moving in the right direction. Is it a WinForms, WPF, ASP.net / Core application because that determines how font information is incorporated.

Comment: Windows form project